# Force new line for isotope

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-isotope

I use isotope javascript on my website. I make nice design and in one page I want to force a new line for the items. How can I do that? I don't want to fit that two elements to be on the same line.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this two ways:

1) Make the isotope container the same width as the items. This can be done by CSS.
   This way you force every isotope item to be on each line as there are not enough space for two items on one line.

2) Set width of isotope item to 100%. This way it will fill the entire width of the container they are inside.

Both options should work.